# jquery addClass working on load, but not with click

Tags: jquery, html

I have a problem with jQuery and bootstrap dropdown.
This method is working:

```
$("ul li#airlines-list.dropdown.hlink").addClass("open");
```

But this method does not work:

```
$(document).on('click', '#register-btn', function()
    {
        $("ul li#airlines-list.dropdown.hlink").addClass("open");
    });
```

-

```
<a id="register-btn" class="register-btn btn btn-custom btn-rnd animated    
fadeInDown wow">Register</a>
<li id="airlines-list" class="dropdown hlink">
<a id="airlines-btn" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true"><i class="ion-plane"></i>
</a>
<ul id="airlines" class="airlines dropdown-menu arrow">
//somestuff 
</ul>
</li>
```

What is wrong?

When I load the page, it immediately shows the drop-down. But when I click on the `register-btn`, it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, two things. First of all, since you have unique IDs (or at least I would hope so - that's the whole idea of html ids...), it's enough to have `$("#airlines-list")` instead of `$("ul li#airlines-list.dropdown.hlink")`.

Secondly, when you bind a click function, you  may want to first select the thing you want to bind it to, not the whole document. Have a look at the code snippet below.

```js
$('#register-btn').on('click', function()
    {
        alert("click");
        $("#airlines-list").addClass("open");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="register-btn" class="register-btn btn btn-custom btn-rnd animated    
fadeInDown wow">Register</a>
<li id="airlines-list" class="dropdown hlink">
<a id="airlines-btn" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true"><i class="ion-plane"></i>
</a>
<ul id="airlines" class="airlines dropdown-menu arrow">
//somestuff 
</ul>
</li>
```

Comment: No reaction with $('#register-btn').on('click', function()
 {
   $("#airlines-list").addClass("open");
 });

Comment: Its the same, the dropdown wont appear

Comment: The class is now added. Now you have to write the function that opens the dropdown when the list element has the class 'open'. In your code above the class wasn't added, and the dropdown didn't appear for me on page load, so now you know that at least the click event is acted upon.

Comment: http://puu.sh/qRjNN/f58942ca7e.png the class is not added when I click the button.

Comment: From the code snippet I posted, after clicking the button, I get: <li id="airlines-list" class="dropdown hlink **open**"> Also you know that binding click works there because of alert.

Comment: This code works here.. but on my website the class is not added

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console? Are you definitely loading jQuery? Basically: are you sure something else that is not in the above code snippets isn't causing the problem?

Comment: Another thing you may want to try is to just set attribute `aria-expanded` to `true`... I don't see any code here that will expand/retract dropdown, based on the class of `#airlines-list`. What's responsible for expanding it is the attribute mentioned above on `airlines-btn`

Comment: I added $("#airlines-btn").attr("aria-expanded","true"); but this is also not working. When I click on the button it flashes purple in the Developer Tools Window, but nothing changes. It's so weird!

Comment: But when I remove the onClick thing, the page loads and the dropdown appears.. its weird

Comment: Are you putting your jQuery code inside a $(document).ready(function() { ... }); callback?

Comment: The code you've written in your question is perfectly fine. Either you click handler is not getting bound, or it's conflicting with something else e.g. another part of your code which might be removing the addClass

Comment: But what is conflicting? There's nothing

Comment: I'd suggest you post your full script here rather than a few snippets